# does OpenCensus is designed to create Custom Metrics over Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, opencensus

According to [Google Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics)

> Using Custom Metrics
>
> This guide describes how to create and use custom metrics. The information is divided into the following sections:
>
> Custom metrics with OpenCensus describes how to use OpenCensus, an open-source monitoring and tracing library, to create custom metrics, add metric data to them, and export them to Cloud Monitoring.
>
> When metrics from OpenCensus are exported to Cloud Monitoring, Monitoring treats them like any other custom metrics.

I have a very simple question: is it possible to create a Custom Metrics to be applied on Firestore only? If so, any scratch idea how will be very appreciated.

Comment: What Custom metrics do you want to apply for Firestore . Have you tried the following link with Firebase metrics: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://medium.com/google-cloud/opencensus-and-firestore-native-34bc1e3a962f. One thing to note is that OpenCensus is being evolved into [OpenTelemetry](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2019/05/opentelemetry-merger-of-opencensus-and.html).